# Regex catastrophic backtracking only in .net

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a regex that runs fine on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and http://regexhero.net/tester/ which is .net. However it timeouts (1h+) in my .net v4.5 code.

```
(?<OuterDescription>[ \t]*--[ \t]+Description:[ \t]+(?!\<Description)(?<Description>\S[^\r\n]{1,})((\r\n|\r|\n)(?![ \t]*--[ \t]*Modified)[^\r\n]*)*)
```

with sample data:

```
-- ========================================================================================================
-- Author:        A Name
-- Create date: 11/26/2012
-- Description:    A description

    --    A multiline description 
        -------------------------------------- Group Name -----------------------------------------
        -- More details
        -- More details
--
--  Modified: 01/7/2012 - Some reason
--  Modified: 12/7/2012 - Some other reason
-- ========================================================================================================
```

my code looks like this

```
var isMatch = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.None, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)).IsMatch(_fileText);
```

hoping OuterDescription captures from `-- Description` to just before `--  Modified`

I've narrowed it down to the `[^\r\n]*` near the end. I do not know how to fix this to not timeout in c#

## Edit:

Thanks for the discussion and answer. It helped move the timeout out of the description. Unfortunately I am still having problems. This is what I have so far

```
[ \t]*--[ \t]+={3,}
(\r\n|\n|\r)
(?<OuterAuthor>[ \t]*--[ \t]+
    Author:[ \t]+
    (?!\<Author)
    (?<Author>\S[^\r\n]+))
(\r\n|\n|\r)
(?<OuterCreateDate>[ \t]*--[ \t]+
    Create\ [Dd]ate:[ \t]+
    (?!\<Create)
    (?<CreateDate>\S[^\r\n]{1,}))
(\r\n|\n|\r)
(?<OuterDescription>[ \t]*--[ \t]+
    Description:[ \t]+
    (?!\<Description)
    (?<Description>\S[^\r\n]+)
    (?<MultilineDescription>((\r\n|\r|\n)|[^\r\n]*)*?)
    (?=(
        [ \t]*--[ \t]*Modified)|(
        [ \t]*--[ \t]*={3,})
    ))
```

That works fine but as soon as I add something after this it will timeout.

Sorry I did not mention this first, I assumed one little greedy star change would be all my problems. To get a sense of the final picture, I have an isAdded bool that will determine whether I check for modified lines (the same way as description) then end with the header/footer. like so

```
var entireCommentHeaderNamedGroupsRegex = headerFooterRegex + newlineRegex
                                          + authorRegex + newlineRegex
                                          + createDateRegex + newlineRegex
                                          + descriptionRegex + newlineRegex
                                          + (_isAdded ? modifiedRegex + newlineRegex : "")
                                          + headerFooterRegex;
```

some more sample data for when it is not modified:

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Garrett Carson
-- Create date: 10/4/2013
-- Description: This is a test
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ThisIsATest
AS
BEGIN
    PRINT 'This is a test'
END
```

Also, as mentioned in the comments, I am fairly new to regular expressions (on this scale) so excuse my terminology if this is not actually catastrophic backtracking.

## Edit 2

As a final edit, I ended up going with a poor man's fsm

```
string currentState = "LookForAuthor"
foreach (var line in lines) {
    switch currentState {
        case "LookForAuthor" : {
            ... use author regex ... save to author variable ...
            if(found) currentState = "LookForCreateDate"
            else throw new InvalidCommentException();
        }
        case "LookForCreateDate": {
            ... use createDate regex ... save to createDate variable ...
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
if (!_isAdded && !(currentState == "Modified-FirstLine" || currentState == "Modified-MoreLines")) {
    throw new InvalidCommentException();
}
```

I then re factored to using enums. The bite sized regexes applied line by line no longer cause timeouts.

Comment: As far as I know a regex never backtracks... Are you sure the timeout is due to the regex? Perhaps you are simply analyzing a gigantic file?

Comment: @CommuSoft You are wrong. Anyway Garret, what output are you expecting to get, perhaps I can come with a better regex instead of finding the problem with yours ?

Comment: You need to specify RegexOptions.Multiline I think, since you're using ^ for beginning of line.

Comment: Garrett, I doubt you're getting catastrophic backtracking with that little snippet of sample text you posted.  How are we supposed to debug your regex if we don't have the input data that actually causes the problem? :)

Comment: @Sniffer: based on my work with compilers I know a regex is compiled to a Non-deterministic finite automaton, such automaton is then modified to a deterministic one (using dynamic programming) deciding input in O(n). Everything that cannot run in linear time, should not be called a regex and can do more than a finite state machine...

Comment: @CommuSoft, we're using the standard industry definition of "regex" as a "any of a family of DSLs for manipulating strings". Your experience in your own area is not adding anything useful to the discussion.

Comment: @CommuSoft I don't know so much about the theory, but I am certain there are some situations when a regex contains constructs that may cause catastrophic backtracking, check [**this link**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) for more info.

Comment: @staafl: Then tell me what features do you use you can't use in a finite state automaton? If you can represent it as such a mechanism it runs in linear time...

Comment: @Sniffer: Only when lazy evaluation is applied. That means that optional aspects (with `*` and `?`) are only parsed if absolutely necessary while a regex normally is greedy parsing all optional aspects unless it cannot be done.

Comment: @CommuSoft, why, backtracking. Refer to Sniffer's link.

Comment: One suggestion, I would avoid using `[ \t]+` and replace using `\s*` and for your middle text simply use `[\S\s]*?`

Comment: @staafl: can you please tell me where you should backtrack, stuff like `?` does not mean one should backtrack, you can use dynamic programming and reduce it to `O(n*m)` with `m` the size of the regex.

Comment: @CommuSoft, perhaps the .NET implementation doesn't use the DP approach.  At any rate, your confusion about backtracking seems to indicate that you're not familiar how actual regex engines work, and I'm afraid I don't have the energy for academic discussions right now. Have a good evening.

Comment: @CommuSoft Here is catastrophic backtracking with only Kleene Star and grouping. `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1000); for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) sb.append("x"); Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(x*x*)*y"); Matcher m = p.matcher(sb.toString()); System.out.println(m.find());`.  It's great if you can build a regex engine that can compile this regex into a NFA that doesn't exhibit catastrophic backtracking, but I'm pretty sure OP doesn't want to build his own regex engine, he wants to use a commonly available one.

Comment: @MikeClark: My regex engine builds an automaton with two states `A` and `B`: A is the start state, an edge starts from `A` and goes to `A` when eating (that's the correct term) `x`, another edge goes from `A` to `B` when eating `y`. `B` is the accepting state. The fact that `C#` uses catastrophic bactracking here is at least strange...

Comment: @Staafl: I already wrote a regex engine myself. Look as long as you don't do context sensitive things like for instance "$1$1" which are allowed in Perl (this means repeating a string like "texttext", everything can be parsed in linear time". From the moment you introduce such things backtracking should be used. But using such a snippet of code should result in linear execution time.

Comment: @Mike Clark: here is a usefull tool that builds automata based on a regex http://hackingoff.com/compilers/regular-expression-to-nfa-dfa After converting to a DFA tools exist to minimize that DFA resulting into two states...

Comment: @CommuSoft it's not strange, it's how every major modern "regular expression" engine works (C#, .NET, Java, Perl, Python, PHP, PCRE, Ruby, JavaScript, C++ Boost, ...).  How can behavior exhibited by every single major programming language be considered strange?

Comment: See previous comment, there exists a DFA who can be generated by a program (the program behind the website) who decides the input in linear time... In a DFA for every character there is only one next state, thus you don't need to backtrack...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to work for me (using `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` for clarity):

```
@"(?<OuterDescription>[ \t]*--[ \t]+
    Description:[ \t]+
    (?!\<Description)
    (?<Description> \S[^\r\n]{1,})
    (?<MultilineDescription>(\r?\n|[^\r\n]*)*?)
    (?=[ \t]*--[ \t]*Modified)
)";
```

In general, nesting greedy quantifiers can lead to the problem you're experiencing. Unfortunately I'm too tired to investigate it in depth, but if you're curious about what's going wrong, I can make a note to look into it later

Comment: Thanks. This helped move the timeout out of the description area. I am still having trouble adding anything following this regex without timeouts however. See edited question

Comment: @GarrettCarson, I'm sorry but looking at your edit, it looks far too complicated for a single regex solution to be appropriate. I recommend you just roll your own state machine parser - it can use regexes internally, but will be much more maintainable and debuggable than having everything plopped in to a single huge regex expression.